# Difference between: Division by a double variable ||| Division by an int variable with a decimal (e.g. 1 / 2.00) ||| Adding (double) to the formula

Tags: c#

Is there any difference between the following alternatives?

In this simple loop there doesn't seem to be any difference between the results, but I wonder if in some cases the different methods would result in some result discrepancy. 
I would like to know whether these methods are exactly the same thing or are there some subtle differences?

x is double:

```
        double x = 2; 
        double sum = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            sum += 1 / ((x - 1) * 2);
            x++;

        }
```

x is int, but (double) before 2 in the formula:

```
        int x = 2; 
        double sum = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            sum += 1 / ((x - 1) * (double)2);
            x++;

        }
```

x is int but 2 is written as decimal:

```
        int x = 2;
        double sum = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            sum += 1 / ((x - 1) * 2.00);
            x++;

        }
```

Comment: You could try to compare the CIL generated by each block and see the differences. Also you might want to try with very large and very small numbers.

Comment: Lets assume the jitter did different things in different cases, what are you going to do with this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Results and their types under comment:

```
        var a = 2;   //int
        var b = 2.0; //double
        var c = 2d;  //double
        var d = 2f;  //float (alias of System.Single)
        var e = 2m;  //decimal
        var f = 2l;  //long
        var g = 2ul; //ulong
        var h = 2.0m; //decimal
        var i = 2.0f; //float

        var t = 1 / 2.0; //double
        var u = 1 / 2; //int!
        var v = 1 / ((6 - 1) * 2); //int!
        var w = 1 / 2 + 6 / 2.0 //int + double = 0 + 3 = 4
```

Looking on your samples:

1. since double takes participate in all formula, result will be double which matches with type of sum and it will be calculated properly according types
2. you explicity converted int to double - look #1
3. 2.00 is double - look #1

So, all samples will be counting sum same way,

**except int type will be overflowed earlier in infinite cycle**

Answer (score 1):

No difference(*) - you are stuck in an endless while loop and won't get out of it.

---

(*) The only way to "*leave*" the loop is by exception ... double takes longer to overflow if you `x++` and `x` is of type `double`...